# mbox ファイルの内容を Linux のテキスト環境で読む方法

Tags: linux, centos, mail

Gmailのメールをアーカイブしてダウンロードしました。ZIP圧縮されており、解凍すると以下の様に `mbox` 形式の1つのファイルが出来ますが、このmboxの中にあるメールをLinuxで読む方法はないでしょうか？

```
Takeout/メール/<圧縮ファイル名>.mbox
```

WindowsであればThunderbird等のソフトがあるようですが、CentOSのSever版を使っているので、GUIではなくテキストベースで読める方法が知りたいです。
ご存知の方はご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: こんな感じでしょうか。[4 Best Command-Line Email Clients For Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/best-commandline-email-clients-for-linux/)